# How to use python regex to recover decimal strings from a website

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this website:

https://download.kde.org/stable/frameworks

to recover the latest series of kde packages.

here is the code I've tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys, os

r = re.compile(r'^[0-9]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$')

url="https://download.kde.org/stable/frameworks"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for tag in html_soup.findAll('a', href=True):
#  if r.match(str(tag['href'])): print(str(tag['href']))
  print(str(tag['href']))
```

If you uncomment the "if r.match ..." line, you can see it doesn't find any matches, but it should print the 5.78 to 5.83 lines.

I think the regex should find strings of the form 5.78, so am I using r.match in the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
r = re.compile(r'^\d+(?:[.,]?\d+)?/?$')
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]?\d+)?`  - an optional occurrence of `.` or `,` and then one or more digits
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: Wiktor! you are a true hero in regex seriously :D I've been following you for a while.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Warm regards to Egypt :)

Comment: This works well for versions of the requested type, e.g. 5.83. Is it possible for the regex to be more general and include versions of the type 5.83.1 or 5.83.14, but still capture 5.83?

Comment: This works for the above question:  r = re.compile(r'^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)?/?$')

Comment: @user1375531 See also [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FrVrs1/1).

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the / in the text.

`r = re.compile(r'^[0-9]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]+/')` should work